# Could Jconsole be used to monitor IBM JDK?

Tags: java, sun, jconsole

Could JConsole be used to monitor IBM JDK? I want to know which Garbage Collection tool is applied Sun JDK and IBM JDK, and it's free.

Comment: Added the Java tag which gets a lot more traffic and thus more likely an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use JConsole to monitor the JVM. But if you are in a Websphere Environment, you should simply use the Administration console to view various counters like the G.C. With the IBM JConsole you will have problem if you enable security.

By the way, the Garbarde Collection is not a separate tool. It is part of the JVM to manage memory. JConsole and the G.B. all comes free with the JDK.

Thank you.